# How can I get this book toc style?

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, books

I would like to have this style in my book written with the book LaTex class. How could I get it?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}    
\setlength{\parindent}{12pt}
\singlespacing
\frenchspacing
\usepackage{microtype} % for better justification
%-------------
% To customize parts, chapters, sections, subsections:
\usepackage[center,sc]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\centering\bfseries}{\centering \huge\thechapter}{0.5em}{\huge}
%--------------
\renewcommand\thepart{\ifcase\value{part}\or ONE\or TWO\or THREE\fi}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\vspace*{-2.5cm}CONTENT}%
%in talbe of contents:
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\normalfont\bfseries\partname~\thepart}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\MakeLowercase\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{.}
\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftdotsep}

% To customize parts, chapters, sections, subsections:
\usepackage[center,sc]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\centering\bfseries}{\centering \huge\thechapter}{0.5em}{\huge}
% Custom pagestyle creation:
\fancypagestyle{custom}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[CO]{\normalfont \itshape \partname \ \thepart}
\fancyhead[CE]{\itshape\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\pagestyle{custom}
%------------
% TO reduce overfull \hbox{} warnings:
\sloppy


\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\part{PART TITE}

\newpage
\chapter{Chapter 1 title}

\lipsum[1-5]

\chapter{Chapter 2 tite}

\lipsum[6-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

My output:
[image]

Comment: Could you  post a minimal (complete) code of  what you've tried, and explain  what's wrong exactly?

Comment: Sure... Question updated.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your MWE but I have used something that just deals with the ToC entries.

```
% booktocprob.tex  SE 565361

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
%%%%%%  new title name and position
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{CONTENTS}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
%%%%% try the part entry re-formbatting
\renewcommand{\cftpartpresnum}{Part }
\setlength{\cftpartnumwidth}{5em}  %% space for ``Part num'' and indents title text
\cftpagenumbersoff{part}           %% no part page numbers
%%%\newcommand{\mypart}[1]{\part{\mbox{}\\ #1}}
\let\oldpart\part
\renewcommand{\part}[1]{\oldpart{\mbox{}\\ #1}}  %% split part and title for ToC
%%%%% change chapter entry formatting
\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftdotsep}  %% dotted leader
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}        %% a . after chapter number

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{Part title}
\chapter{Chapter 1 title}
\chapter{Chapter 2 title}

\end{document}
```

My main difficulty was getting the two-line Part entry in the ToC. Eventually I resolved this by redefining `\part` to have the title in a second line. (You may want to try the commented out `\mypart` macro to see if that works better for you.)